# generating documentation with companion guides using appledocs?

Tags: documentation-generation, appledoc

we are working on several internal projects.
We would like to keep all documentation in the same place. We are using appledocs for the code documentation. But we need some pages (like apple have their companion guides) that we would like to bundle with the same documentation. Is this possible with appledocs? and if so, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently possible.

All documentation found here https://github.com/tomaz/appledoc/blob/master/IncludingExternalDocumentation.markdown